# Convert feet to inches

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that converts inches to feet, and returns the number of feet and the number of leftover inches if any.  I tried this:

```
public class Convertor
{
/**
 * Fields
 */
    private int inches;
    private int feet;
    private int yards;
    private int leftoverInches;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Convertor
     */
    public Convertor()
    {
        inches=0;
        feet=0;
        yards=0;
        leftoverInches=0;
    }

    /**
     * Mutator method to convert inches to feet
     */
    public void convertValuesInchtoFeet(int anyInches)
    {
        inches=anyInches;
        feet=(anyInches * 0.083);
        leftoverInches= inches%feet;
        System.out.println(inches+" inches = " +feet+" feet.");
        System.out.println("There are " +leftoverinches +"  leftover inches");

    }
```

Doesn't work.

Someone help me on this, please!  Thank you.

Comment: What result are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: Well, `12 * 0.083 == .996`. You'd be better of dividing by 12 directly.

Comment: Look at your compilers output when you build your program. It gives you hints on mistakes that can be hard to find from looking at the source code.

Comment: @jtm: There is no reason for your variables to be instance members.  You should make them local variables (declare them inside of the method instead).

Comment: Tomorrow I will ask the question “how do I divide by 13?” The day after it will be “how do I divide by 14?” — soon I will be able to divide by all positive integers smaller than 1000! \o/

Comment: Hey guys, lets set our integers to zero just in case some magic happens and they are initiated with a value other than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int inches = 34;
int feet = inches / 12;
int leftover = inches % 12;
System.out.println(feet + " feet and " + leftover + " inches");
```

Comment: or    leftover = inches - (feet * 12);

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public void convertValuesInchtoFeet(int anyInches)
    {
        inches = anyInches;
        feet = Math.floor(inches/12);
               //if int than no need for the Math.floor()
        leftoverInches = inches%12;
        System.out.println(inches + " inches = " + feet + " feet.");
        System.out.println("There are " + leftoverInches + " leftover inches");

    }
```

Comment: The `Math.floor()` is superfluous; you're doing integer division.  But +1 for pointing out the real way to do it.

Comment: @Mark, ddnt see that feet was an `int`. still works no matter what ^_^

Comment: You dont need the floor, I think - integer division always rounds down, I beleive.

Comment: @Neal: it's actually whether `inches` is an `int` that is relevant in deciding if `floor` is needed or not.  If `feet` is a `double` you'd still be doing integer division.

Comment: @Mark Peters, i left the comment arbitrary now, edit if u feel its necessary :-)

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason your code doesn't work is because you're doing

```
leftoverInches = inches%feet;
```

Suppose you gave it 13 inches.  You would have feet = 1 (13 * 0.083 rounded down), and inches = 13 % 1 = 0.  What you mean to do was

```
leftoverInches = inches%12;
```

With 13, 13%12 = 1, which is indeed the number of leftover inches.

A smaller but still important error is that you multiply by 0.083, which is NOT 1/12, and will give you serious inaccuracies.  For example, if you enter 1,000,000 inches, you will get

```
1000000 * 0.083 = 83000 feet
```

But

```
1000000 / 12 = 83333 feet rounded down
```

So you would be 333 feet off.