# Java - convert any unit to any unit

Tags: java

I am trying to make a method that will convert any unit to any larger unit.  I need to, I'm guessing provide parameters for each input, so I'm guessing it needs to ask the user parameters for..startingNum, conversionFactor, outPutNum, but I'm unsure where to begin.  I already made one with inches:

```
    public Convertor()
{
    inches=0;
    feet=0;
    yards=0;
    leftoverInches=0;
}

/**
 * Mutator method to convert inches to feet
 */
public void convertValuesInchtoFeet(int anyInches)
{
    inches=anyInches;
    feet=anyInches/12;
    leftoverInches= anyInches%12;
    System.out.println(inches+" inches = " +feet+" feet.");
    System.out.println("There are " +leftoverInches +"  leftover inches");

}
```

Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you need enums (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: @user:Perhaps you should provide feedback to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424390/convert-feet-to-inches) before moving on to a new one?  By the way in case you forgot your username after just 20 minutes it was [jtm22](http://stackoverflow.com/users/675495/jtm22).

Comment: Try to think of ways to generalize from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424350/convert-feet-to-inches

Comment: This assumes that all units can be converted using a simple multiplier. Whatbout temperature C to F?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any unit to any unit is a bit vague, but generally you need to provide:
a) input number
b) input unit
c) output unit

Assuming you want to make a function that does general conversion between feet, inches and yards.

I'd take a look at the [TimeUnit API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) and see if you get any ideas on a different way of doing it. Its made using enumerations with methods in them, but I don't know how familiar you are with Enums.

Oh yeah, TimeUnit is used like this:
`TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1); // Returns 1000`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enums](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html&rct=j&q=java%20enum&ei=5p2LTfDLIYz6swPQvPmLCQ&usg=AFQjCNHjC_wUJoD8PbkSKEbnfO2tM9yZ5g&sig2=XBAaT_fvZWlYdI2FfSLuKg&cad=rja) to store the various unit names. e.g,

```
public Enum Unit {
    MM, CM, INCH, FEET;
}
```

Follow the Planets example in the above page. You can create a property called number of millimeters for each unit (assuming millimeters is your smallest unit) and a function  getNumberOfMillimeters() to return it. So, CM.getNumberOfMillimeters() would return 10 and so on for each unit. Then, you can create a generic function like this:

```
public double convert(Unit unit1, Unit unit2, double input) {
      return input*(unit2.getNumberOfMillimeters()/unit1.getNumberOfMillimeters());
}
```

I hope it helps. Comment if you find any difficulty in following it.

Comment: i don't know..this seems too advanced.  I'm just trying to add in an inputnumber, conversionfactor to multiply by, and an output number.  does that sound like it'll be easy to do?

Comment: @user675570: This is the correct approach and not needlessly advanced. The problem with direct conversion factors is that you need to store one for every pair of units. So the number of conversion factors you need to calculate and store grows geometrically with the number of units you want to support. This way essentially uses one unit as the base - a mid-point for the conversion - and thus drastically reduces the number of conversion factors you have to hard-code.

Comment: Incidentally, you can see another working example here: http://code.google.com/p/simplelatlng/source/browse/src/main/java/com/javadocmd/simplelatlng/util/LengthUnit.java

Answer (score 1):

Create enum:

```
enum Unit {
    INCHES, FEETS, YARDS
}
```

And your amount class:

```
class Amount {
    private Unit unit;
    private double amount;
    //getters and setters
}
```

**And main parts: factorsMap** which has two parameters (source unit, destination unit) connected with some value:

```
sourceUnit * value = destinationUnit,
```

then convert method looks like this:

```
public void convert(Amount source, Amount destination) {
    double factor = factorsMap.get(source.getUnit(), destination.getUnit());
    destination.setAmount(source.getAmount() * factor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use UCUM (Unified Code for Units of Measure). This can help to develop a converter in [Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ucum-lib/ucum-lib/0.2.2). What UCUM is, is explained by UCUM itself with:

> The Unified Code for Units of Measure (UCUM) is a code system intended to include all units of measures being contemporarily used in international science, engineering, and business.

**I have used UCUM for my project:** [calculate.plus](https://calculate.plus/)

Comment: I just discovered UCUM last night and it’s beautiful! I’ve always dreamt of a library like this...